# Find point B on line L given points AC where angle ABC equals angle X

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Trying to work out this tricky trigonometry question for a game I am programming. My maths knowledge is basic so if possible please keep the answer as basic as possible.

Need the formula to calculate point B on an infinite line L given two points AC where the angle ABC is equal to a specified angle X.

I understand also that there are normally two points with the specified angle X on the line L

So for example, if line L passed through points (0,10) and (10,0) and point A = (2,5) and point C = (5,2) and I wanted to find the target angle of 90 degrees then point B would be (5,5). Now, what if my target angle was 45 or 5 degrees what would point B be?

New image to illistate: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwjKE.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, John for your help. I had seen that question but I was not sure if that was what I was looking for it seemed like the inverse of my question. I have updated my question to try and explain better.

Comment: You're welcome. I've checked the other question and, to me, it seems to be asking the same thing as what you are, i.e., in both cases you are giving $2$ points not on a line & asking what point on the line would form a specified angle. I don't see how it's the inverse of your question. Please check again.